# Blockchain.info Payment API -> Callback gets a 302?

Tags: blockchain.info, api

I want to integrate the Blockchain.info Payment API and everything works fine so far. The callback works and triggers the code on my server, if a payment comes in. But if I check the callback log of Blockchain.info, it says, it retrieved the status code 302 back from my server when calling the callback url. If I check the callback url in the browser or with curl, I just get a status code 200.

Is that some known problem? Or does anybody know whats the issue is here? Or is everything fine and the blockchain.info service can read the *ok* from my server? Otherwise my callback will be banned if I read the docs correctly...

Answer (score 0):

normally it has to be 200, the 302 mean that the requested resource resides temporarily under a different URI.

Dont block "GET" requests on your code because blockchain use GET method to send your notifications about the transactions.

Use your full domain name including the leading www example :

http://www.example.com/callback....

In case of https ! make sure you include it in the callback URL.